# Is there a way to fade one image out completely and fade another one in completely with transition?

Tags: html, css, image, transition

As the title states, is there a way to fade one image out completely and fade another one in completely with transition? I'm looking to do this with the new transition property in CSS. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried google?  Generally speaking, questions posted to StackOverflow should show some attempt to solve the problem first.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to fade one image out completely and fade another one in completely with transition?

Yes.

> I'm looking to do this with the new transition property in CSS

Opacity can be animated:

```
.yourImage {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade {
   opacity: 0;
}
```